# How the pattern of fertilization path is determined before the cell division to form the blastocyst? Is it individually specific?

Tags: reproduction

After sperm meets ovum,the inactive nucleus starts following a particular path inside the zygote rather chase a path.This path is biologically known as fertilization path (as mentioned in an article of a local magazine named "science reporter"). But my question is how the pattern of the path is determined?  I came to know from the article that for every individual this particular path is very specific. Is it true?  If so then what does that specific path determine and why is it specific for every individual?

Comment: Can anybody please make me understand it?

Comment: This is a tad unclear.. are you asking about molecular pathways that underlie embryogenesis starting at fertilization? Even so, this is very broad and there are many players involved. You may need to clarify exactly which aspects need explaining.

Comment: Is the article one of these: http://nopr.niscair.res.in/handle/123456789/30751 ?  It seems like "Science Reporter" is behind a pay wall, but I was looking at least for the article.

Comment: No..I don't think they post online articles. But I checked. The article isn't from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the more commonly used term is "copulation path," and I don't ether is used as a formal biological term, but rather in models for the public.  The term that is used in literature is "pronuclear fusion" for the process as a whole, and I don't know of a more technical term for the path itself.  Your inability to find information may have been linked to terms used.

Anyway, the copulation path doesn't have as much variability as the penetration path, which is what determines the copulation path.  The copulation path tends to be a relatively straight line between the two pronucleoli, dictated by and pushed along the cytoskeleton ([Lian et al, 2014](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25061094)).  It is worth noting that it is often not the shortest straight line (think of the number of lines between a smaller sphere and a larger one), but still a relatively straight line.  People tend to care about this, because what ever the copulation path, it sets the axis of division, which can effect in vitro fertilization techniques, particularly in plants.

Getting at what I think you are trying to ask, the penetration path is variable because it is an oscillatory phenomenon.  You actually have to move back in the fertilization process to the sperm impact angle ([Hedrih et al, 2015](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25659799) is the coolest model I've seen of this) to see how this can change.

To understand oscillatory phenomenon in general, you need to understand that a lot of the processes in biology are driven by the chaotic (used in the formal since) vibrating or shaking of molecules and fluid microcurrents.  This means that we can not know (regardless of how sensitive we measure) the conditions specific enough to create the specific path.  These things are not tied to genes or to the person in general (perhaps exuding of mutations/disorders that effect the morphology of sperm or egg).  Rather it is specific to any single fertilization reaction simple because of chance/chaos.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You really understood my problem well and I am sattisfied with your answer.

Comment: @Demietra95 It's still not a wonderfully worded question.  The "because I read..." section is both poor grammar and doesn't say where you read it.  You should always include references/links to the source materials you've been looking at that lead into a question.

Comment: I am really sorry for my mistakes :( Actually I read it in a local science magazine and there it was referred as fertilization path.

Comment: @Demietra95  That's fine, you can go back and edit the question to include a reference to the magazine article.  It doesn't matter if it's not in English.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just edited it. Though the magazine is an English science of magazine, it's local,  it's mostly popular in our country but probably not outside.